# Comparator not working

Tags: java, comparator

We have written following code which is not working for `Comparator` compare method.

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
{
    if (o2 == null) return 1;
    else if (o1 == null) return -1;

    MailObject a = (MailObject)o1;
    MailObject b = (MailObject)o2;
    return a.getType() < b.getType()? 1 : -1;
}
```

where the `getType()` method returns an integer value.
and following code is working fine

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
{
    if (o2 == null) return 1;
    else if (o1 == null) return -1;

    MailObject a = (MailObject)o1;
    MailObject b = (MailObject)o2;
    return a.getType() - b.getType();
}
```

If we remove ternary operator in return statement, then it is working fine. If we add equal check, then also it is working fine. Why?

first block of code giving following exception:

```
07:45:22 ERROR c.c.servlet.MyServlet - Comparison method violates its general contract!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
               at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
               at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
               at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
               at java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
               at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
               at java.util.List.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
               at java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

Comment: What error you are getting? And What is MailObject class?

Comment: why do you need to use the ternary operator?

Comment: **Why are you not explicitly typing your comparator?!**

Comment: in first approach,you are handling only greater than and less than and you are not handling equal case,so its complaining.

Comment: any simple class object. which is containing simple properties.

Comment: compare method returning  a negative int  means  o1 < o2. If positive 
o1 > o2 . So what do you expect by `if (o2 == null) return 1;
    else if (o1 == null) return -1;` ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initial implementation breaks the general contract for [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)s by not dealing correctly (i.e., returning 0) when the two types are equal.

Instead of trying to implement the comparison logic between two integers by yourself, why not let `Integer` do [what it knows best](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-)?

```
return Integer.compare(a.getType(), b.getType());
```

Comment: Can we have something like this for nullable arguments?

Comment: Can you explain what contract basically between Comparator interface and our implementation.

Comment: @Basilevs in Java 7 and below, I'd just handle `null`s explicitly, as OP has. In Java 8 and above, you have some syntactic sugar for this with `Comparator.nullsFirst` and `Comparator.nullsLast`.

Comment: @VinaySharma the general contract of `Comparator#compare` is to return a negative value if the first argument should come first, a positive value if the second argument should come first and 0 if they are "equal". In your implementation, where you're attempting to sort by `getType()`, you do not return 0 if both objects return the same value for this method.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to return 0 for equal values.

Following always true for non-null x:

```
(x < x ? 1 : -1) == -1
```

Comment: Assuming that `a.getType` returns `int`; `a.getType() - b.getType()` will return 0 if their results are equivalent.

Comment: What about ternary operator in question?

Answer (score 0):

Both your comparators are NOT the same, they are actually opposite of each other.

In the first case, if `a` is lesser, you return a **positive value**.

In second, if `a` is lesser, you return a **negative value**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code which would take into account if they are equal, which this will not.  It will return -1 if they are equal or b is greater than a.  So try...

return a.getType() < b.getType()? -1 : a.getType() > b.getType()? 1 : 0;

In this it tests if a is less than b, if it is, it returns -1, if it is not, it then tests if a is greater than b, if that is true it returns 1, if not they must be equal so it returns 0;

Of course, you can change those values to whatever suits you.